# Context manager to retry block after exception

Tags: python, loops, exception, contextmanager

Is it possible to use a context manager to execute a block of code, and keep retrying it if it throws a specific exception. Something like this:

```
with RetryOnException(Some.Exception):
    obj.doit()
```

Which would be the equivalent of:

```
while True:
    try:
        obj.doit()
    except Some.Exception:
        logger.exception("failed")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        break
```

I have many calls to a method which can throw an exception, and it would be highly inconvenient to have to write all that boilerplate each time.

Answer (score 3):

No, a context manager is not capable of iterating over the code body it contains.  To do something similar to what your require:

```
def retry(f, on_exception=None, exception_type=Exception):
    # a default exception handler
    on_exception = on_exception or lambda e: pass

    while True:
        try:
            return f()
        except exception_type as e:
            on_exception(e)
```

Then you could call it as eg:

```
def my_handler(e):
    logger.exception("failed")
    time.sleep(1)

retry(obj.doit, on_exception=my_handler)
```

Or more concisely in this case, simply:

```
retry(obj.doit, lambda e: logger.exception("failed"), time.sleep(1))
```